# App shortcut returning error "App is not installed "

Tags: android, android-shortcut

I am trying to create shortcut on android Launcher icon

Created shortcuts.xml in xml folder

`android:targetPackage="com.example.logger"/> //This is the package which contains activity to be launched. This is not application id 
</shortcut>`

Also added in Android Manifest

Now the shortcut appears but on click of shortcut it shows “App is not installed”

Answer (score 0):

**Take a look at this article, it will help you on how to create shortcuts**

[shortcuts android](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts)